# Is there a 1-line solution to turn a scalar into a n-length array with the same value in each element

Tags: python, numpy

I am looking for an one line alternative to

```
a = 3
n = 5
b = np.ones(n)
b *= a
```

Basically, I would like to create a vector with n size and each item has the same value.

Comment: `b=np.ones(n)*a`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`np.full`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.full.html) to create an empty array of a given size and specifying a `fill_value`:

```
np.full(n, a)
# array([3, 3, 3, 3, 3])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> a = 420
>>> n = 4
>>> [a] * n
[420, 420, 420, 420]
```